# How to set maximum size of image from image Picker in Flutter

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

this is my code

```
chooseImage() async {
    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    imagePath = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely block files over a certain size, you can check the size of the file using it's length property, and handle the result accordingly

```
chooseImage() async {
    var maxFileSizeInBytes = 2 * 1048576; // 2MB (You'll probably want this outside of this function so you can reuse the value elsewhere)

    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );
    var imagePath = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();

    var fileSize = imagePath.length; // Get the file size in bytes
    if (fileSize <= maxFileSizeInBytes) {
        // File is the right size, upload/use it
    } else {
        // File is too large, ask user to upload a smaller file, or compress the file/image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imageQuality` properties. The higher the quality, the larger the file size of the image.

```
chooseImage() async {
  XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    imageQuality: 50, // Set the quality to 50%
  );
  imagePath = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();  
}
```

Comment: But its not that i want...I need to restrict the user to upload image lesser than 2mb

Comment: this is may not be possible but u can define these 3 options to control the size. maxWidth: ..., maxHeight: ..., imageQuality: ......,